# There are some missing modules: ['matplotlib.patches', 'matplotlib.path', 'matplotlib.pylab', 'matplotlib.pyplot']

Tags: python, matplotlib, panda3d

I have a problem to create .p3d file using packp3d.
The problem is that: when I try generate the .p3d file, I get this warning:

```
There are some missing modules: ['matplotlib.patches', 'matplotlib.path', 'matplotlib.pylab', 'matplotlib.pyplot']
```

If I try to launch my p3d file it gives me an error because matplotlib modules are missing.

I'm new on python and panda3d developing so I asked a co-worker, who is an expert in Panda3D, and he said me that probably is a python problem.

Comment: Have you installed matplotlib?

Comment: yes, infact if i run my project from Eclips it runs without problems

Comment: Do you perhaps have two versions of Python installed and only one has matplotlib? (I don't know much about Panda3D but it's a common problem for other libraries)

Comment: Yeah, i have python2.7, python3, python3.2 but only python2.7 has matplotlib...i use python2.7 as intepreter in Eclipse...it's possible that panda3d use a differt python?

Comment: Yes it's entirely possible (I don't know though). Panda3D might even have it's own version of Python installed somewhere. For example I had two versions of Python 2.7 on my computer, one was my "regular" version and one was a version that some analysis software installed for it's own use. Unfortunately I can't really help you anymore but it's definitely something to think about.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write that i'm in linux, and in linux Panda3d doesn't have it's own version of Python, it uses the system version...right?